# Using Redis as an Object Cache with Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, redis, woocommerce, objectcache

i'm trying to run a big ecommerce using Woocommerce and i'm facing some problems. Website has 10000 products per language ( 2 languages ) with many of them variable.

For now i'm trying to cache it using W3 Total Caches Page Cache ( Disk Enchanced ) and Browser Cache.Site is running on PHP 7.0.1 with mariadb 5.7 .

The big problem is when i'm trying to use Redis as an object cache. Due to the fact i'm saving some large queries as a transient redis is strugling to fetch and save the data after beeing flushed.

Even though , after caching happens, i'm getting strange results on the frontend ( wrong data cached to products, missing variation options, switching back and forth beetween languaged etc)

I'm using Redis Object Cache plugin to make the connection beetween wordpress and redis server happen ( by Till Krüss ).
VM Running CentOS 7 and as far as i know redis-server has its default configuration.
I've enabled key cache salt on wp-config.php but problems keeps comming.
My question is how can debug and benchmark it.

Is there any settings required to the server to make redis run as an object cache? How can i find the optimal ram needed for redis ?
What are my alternatives? (beside apcu).

Sorry for the long question, but i'm struggling a lot to find a well documented answer arround the web.
Thanks in advance